# Save and Continue Logic Understand

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm developing on Asp.net MVC 4 and i need to action Save and Continue Editing
   But i didn't understand how it's must be.

Everyting is ok about creating an entity. Entity framework send an entity(ID is empty) to
  sql server. after that sql server insert that entity, but I want to save and continue
logic how can get entity id after sql insert. how can i do that ?

Have a nice day, Thank you. i tried but i didn't

Comment: Make sure that you have "Identity Specification, Is Identity" turned on in the database, refresh your edmx and the Id should get updated on insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After inserting the object to the entity . you can get that id by accessing the id of that  inserted object

```
Person person = new Person();
db.Persons.AddObject(person); //Inserting object to the entity
db.SaveChanges(); // saving to the database through context

//getting ID
int PersonId = person.PersonId;
```